# Dell notebook overheating without manual fan control

Tags: dell, overheating, fan, fancontrol

On my Dell 7570 the fans are not running when booting Ubuntu. There would be the solution to control the fan by `i8kmon`. That works mostly, but sometimes (especially after STR) it does not and even a restart of the daemon does not help. In case `i8kmon` is not running and i'm using the CPU a bit it simply runs quick to around 100°C and sometimes the computer dies.

Is there a known way to fallback to BIOS-based fancontrol? Even full speed would be okay.